# Python Selenium is missing elements when scrolling

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to webscrape the website https://cs.trade/ I want to scrape the name of the item, the price and the game the item is from. I have chosen to use Selenium to scrape it. I am scraping these values by scraping all the `item-divs` nested in the `scroll-div` `<div id="box-bot-inventory" class="box-items">`. When I scroll down the `scroll-div`, more of the `item-divs` appear so I have written code to scroll in the `scroll-div` to generate more `item-divs` so I can scrape everything. The problem is when I scroll too far down and I try to scrape the price element the first few `item-divs` return nothing and I cannot figure out why.

When I set the 34 inside the range to 33 it works fine. But I want a larger number so I can scroll down further and scrape more results. Here is the code used to scroll down the scroll-div to generate more item-divs.

```
vertical_ordinate = 0
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wrapper-box-bot-inventory']")
for i in range(0, 34):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", element, vertical_ordinate)
    vertical_ordinate += 112
    print(vertical_ordinate)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is the code I use to scrape the results

```
item_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-price")
items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "single-item      ")

for i in range(len(items)):
    game_type = items[i].get_attribute("data-type") 
    if ("_item" not in game_type): #not: (dota2_item, rust_item tf2_item)
        name = items[i].get_attribute("data-name")
        price = item_prices[i].text

        print(name + " Price " + price)
```

Below is the full code. EDIT: I've changed the code so that selenium auto opens Chrome DevTools automatically and added a pause after the loop has finished. Once the loop has finished I go into the DevTools and press Ctrl+F and then type
`//small[@class='item-price']` then I press the down button search next, then I press the up button search up, then I go back to the terminal and press enter a key to unpause the program and now the prices are displayed/scraped. This isn't an ideal since I need to manually do this, so I hope it may help in identifying a way to solve this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


URL = "https://cs.trade/"

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(10)

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wrapper-box-bot-inventory']")
vertical_ordinate = 0
for i in range(0, 34):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", element, vertical_ordinate)
    vertical_ordinate += 112
    print(vertical_ordinate)
    time.sleep(1)

input("Press key to unpause")

item_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-price")
items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "single-item      ")


for i in range(len(items)):
    game_type = items[i].get_attribute("data-type") #dota2_item, rust_item tf2_item
    if "_item" not in game_type:
        name = items[i].get_attribute("data-name")
        price = item_prices[i].text

        print(name + " Price " + price)
```

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: I want to increase the number in the range to 50 maybe, so I can scrape more results. But the problem I have outlined is that when I increase it to 34, problems arise in which the first couple of results don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

i do know what u want to do, but try substitute the scroll with element.scrollIntoView(), passing the element on arguments

Comment: This doesn't work, it just scrolls the outer scroll into view of the div im trying to scroll.